# Is there a way to add disk space to a Postgres instance hosted on an EC2 server?

Tags: postgresql

I have a machine that has 512 GB disk space on which I am running a Postgres instance. The problem is that the disk is almost full and I need to increase the size of the available disk space.

I know I could backup the disk as snapshot and then use that snapshot to create a new volume with more size and attach it to the original disk. But this takes too long and I do not want to be doing it as I can not afford the downtime.

Is there a way I can bring up another machine and then somehow tell the postgres to use disk space from that server for this database?

Comment: What kind of operating system running ? Please check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59252/postgresql-extending-database-storage-when-disk-is-full.